# OnEdit function Does not recognize pasted (ctrl-p) Values as being a cell edit. Is it possible to get it to do so?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I've got an script in my google sheet that stamps time codes into specific cells when a name is entered in the column next to it... However the script does not work when the names are copied and pasted into the column... is there a work around for this issue that will trigger the script on a cell having a value pasted into it?

script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
var s = e.source.getActiveSheet().getName();
var cols = [3, 5, 7, 10, 12, 14, 17, 19, 21];
var curDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-4", "dd/hmm a")


if 
  (s !== 'SHEET 1' && s 
!== 'SHEET 2' || cols.indexOf(e.range.columnStart) ==-1 || 
!e.value) return;
e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(curDate);
}
```

Thanks fellas!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be a bug with a possible workaround. It appears the range may be being returned to the event object but not the value.

Instead of:

```
!e.value
```

Try:

```
e.range.getValue().length == 0
```

Or:

```
e.range.getValue() == ""
```

https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4816

Comment: Thank you ScampMichael. That fixed it right up! I am curious though... when you make mention of there being a "bug" does this mean that my initial attempt at the script was theoretically correct? I only ask out of piece of mind:)

Thanks again for the answer, greatly appreciated.

Comment: your initial attempt was correct. it should have worked the way you tried it. the reason it does not work is because there is a bug. Click on the link and star the issue to be advised if and when it is corrected.

Comment: Starred the issue! Thanks again ScampMichael:):):)