# Run a function when a cell value changes (onEdit Function)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

in the below sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F22Z19gi9WRaYbsrvlDyuiJX5VXfppAlCPzB5bjdMN8/edit?usp=sharing

From the script editor, I added the below code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheetName = 'Sheet2'
  var cellName = 'C2'

  var sortSheet = e.range.getSheet()

  if (sortSheet.getName() === sheetName) {
    if (e.range.getValue().length === cellName) {
      var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2");
      var e = sh.getRange(2, 3).getValues();
      var m = 'Test Message';
      var subject = 'Test Subject';
      MailApp.sendEmail(e, subject, m);
    }
  }
}
```

The purpose is to trigger the MailApp function when a "C2" cell value is changed in sheet2

I tested the same script but on sheet1 (where I add the cell values) and it worked but, however, when I try to apply on sheet2 (where the values are copied from sheet1), the script does not work. Any help, Thanks in advance

**Please note the sheet is editable so you are very welcome to edit the script**

Comment: You mean that you want the trigger to run on a sheet that is not manually edited by a human?

Comment: As I mentioned in the question "The purpose is to trigger the MailApp function when a "C2" cell value is changed in sheet2"  whether the value is manually edited or as a result of a formula. I mean (as I understand) if the value is changed, the script is supposed to detect the value change and run the function, isn't it?

Comment: There is a big difference between the two cases, because `onEdit` fires only when the value is changed by a human. If it is changed by a script you need a workaround.

Comment: Would you recommend something. Also I found a similar thread @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30223833/onedit-function-does-not-recognize-pasted-ctrl-p-values-as-being-a-cell-edit and what mentioned in the thread is to get the onEdit runs when the value is copy/pasted from another sheet. What we are trying to do here is to accomplish the same thing but instead of ctrl c/ctrl v, we use a formula to copy the values. What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After chatting, we decided to incorporate the mailing inside the already available doPost() function.

```
function doPost (e) {


.... 

var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)
var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1
var newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
  return header === 'Timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
})

sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])
var email = newRow[1];
var subject = 'XXXXXXXXX';
var body = 'XXXXXXX';
MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body);

...... //rest of the code
```

}

Comment: "MailApp requires authorization and will probably not work on a simple onEdit trigger"
I did give an authorization (for both the sheet and the mail apps) first time when I opened the "Current Project Triggers" and installed the onEdit trigger

"Replace the code you have with..."
I did, but still no luck

Comment: Ok. Then I suggest you share a copy of your spreadsheet with script attached.

Comment: Note that an onEdit trigger requires an actual edit of the sheet. A recalculation of a formula does NOT count as an edit. In that case you can (maybe) create a function that you can run from the menu to send the mail?

Comment: "Then I suggest you share a copy of your spreadsheet with script attached"
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F22Z19gi9WRaYbsrvlDyuiJX5VXfppAlCPzB5bjdMN8/edit?usp=sharing (Editable)

Answer (score 1):

### How to fire a trigger on non-human edit

- Both simple and installable Apps Script `onEdit` triggers are [retricted](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#restrictions) to human-made changes
- In addition, [simple](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) triggers

> cannot access services that require authorization. For example, a
>   simple trigger cannot send an email because the Gmail service requires
>   authorization, but a simple trigger can translate a phrase with the
>   Language service, which is anonymous.

**A workaround would be to replace the `onEdit` trigger throguh an installable `onChange trigger`**

- The `onchange` trigger has less limitations, e.g. it can be triggered by the sheets formula [`IMPORTRANGE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en)
- What you need to do is to create a new, empty spreadsheet and paste the formula `IMPORTRANGE("paste here the spreadsheet_url of the original spreadsheet", "Sheet2!E2")` in cell `E2`.
- click on `Allow access`
- Now each update of "E2" in "Sheet2" of the original spreadsheet will update the new spreadsheet - and this will fire the onChange trigger.

Just modify your code as following:

```
function onChange() { 
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var e = sh.getRange(2, 3).getValue();
  var m = 'Test Message';
  var subject = 'Test Subject';
  Logger.log("sending");
  MailApp.sendEmail(e, subject, m);
}
```

Comment: Yes, this worked too. Perfect workaround. Thanks ziganotschka