# Trigger script when a specific cell value in another sheet chan

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hello everyone so I am using this google sheets script below that copies the entire contents of one sheet to another sheet. I would like for this script to only trigger when a there is value change in cell TI of the sheet that being copied. Does any one have an idea how to do this? Thank you so much for you help.

```
function Packaging() {
 var t = SpreadsheetApp.openById('sheetid');


var pp = t.getSheetByName('UP');
var ppk = pp.getRange(1,1,pp.getLastRow(),pp.getLastColumn()).getValues();
var data = []                       
for (var i = 0; i< ppk.length ; i++){
if(ppk[i][24] == "Yes")        
{
data.push(ppk[i])
}
}


var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();


var sp = s.getSheetByName('DOWN');
sp.getRange(1,1,sp.getLastRow(),sp.getLastColumn()).clearContent();
sp.getRange(1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);  

sp.deleteColumns(29, 7);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=='Sheet being copied' && e.range.columnStart=="col of cell" && 
  e.range.rowStart=="row of cell" && e.value=="special value of cell") {
    var vA=sh.getDataRange().getValues();
    e.source.getSheetByName('sheet to copy to').getRange(1,1,vA.length,vA[0].length).setValues(vA);
  }
}
```

Perhaps this for changes in value:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=='Sheet being copied' && e.range.columnStart=="col of cell" && 
  e.range.rowStart=="row of cell" && e.oldValue && e.value!=e.oldValue) {
    var vA=sh.getDataRange().getValues();
    e.source.getSheetByName('sheet to copy to').getRange(1,1,vA.length,vA[0].length).setValues(vA);
  }
}
```

Comment: hey coopyer thank you for helping me :) i got this error when i tried it SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment (line 3, file "Code.gs")      Was i suppose to your code below my code or just replace my entire code? Because i replaced it. I would like to the script to trigger  whenever there is change in cell T1 of the copied sheet.

Comment: Thank worked :) what if i wanted it to only change when the value in t1 increases or decreases. I have a conta formula in T1

Comment: By the way.  onEdit() only works for user edits.  Not when cell value changes due to script actions or formula calculations.

Comment: ahh i was unaware. Would that be possible to make it change due to formula calculation?

Comment: That's not possible?

Comment: the onchange may be able to be used to trigger the script by using the important formula

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: The problem is that we are on a server and they have to be careful about changes that occur due to values changing in a spreadsheets because if everyone implemented those kinds of triggers the server would not be able to keep up.

Comment: So if i create new spreadsheet and put the formula in that sheet, then use the import range formula in cell T1, every time it imports that would trigger the on change

Comment: This is post where i saw someone give that solution for non human changes - give it a look it may be interesting but thank you so much for the help i really appreciate it  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60090578/run-a-function-when-a-cell-value-changes-onedit-function

Comment: If a user copies and pastes it will generate a onEdit trigger if a script does it, it won't generate an onEdit trigger.  But you don't have to take my word for it.  Try it yourself see if you can get it trigger.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214439/discussion-between-4dawin-and-cooper).