How do you use the on change trigger for JavaScript for a Google Sheet to change the color of the font for a cell populated with a filter function?
I have a cell with a filter function. I want to set the found color for the cells that are populated by the filter function when their value changes.
The onEdit works for cells that are manually changed but not for cells populated with the filter function. Can you do it by writing an onChange function?

Have you considered conditional formatting instead? You also have this thread that might reply to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60090578/run-a-function-when-a-cell-value-changes-onedit-function

Google Apps Script has two types of triggers: simple and installable. None of them are "listening" for formula recalculation; however, you might change your logic and listen for the event that triggers the formula recalculation, in this case, the recalculation of the FILTER function.
If the ranges referred to by the FILTER function are manually edited, then the on-edit, simple or installable triggers should work fine; you must adapt the code appropriately.
If the referred ranges are edited by an API, you might use the on-change installable trigger, which might be more complex.
On the other hand, if you are using a volatile function like NOW, TODAY, RAND, or RANDBETWEEN, you might have to use a time-driven trigger or client-side JavaScript on a modeless dialog or sidebar to poll the results of FILTER or a cell that is recalculated simultaneously for changes.
Using on-change DOM event, I think, is a lot more convoluted, and it's very likely that it will be hard to maintain because of the complexity of Google Sheets.
